# Need jshint error on forgotten 'var' keyword

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm using JSHINT, and noticed that it doesn't throw an error when I have the following code:

```
function barfoo() {
    a = 10;
}
```

I want an error for every globally defined variable. I have now the following gulp task

```
var options =  {
    laxcomma: true,
    strict: true,
    validthis: true
};

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('di.js')
      .pipe(jshint(options));
});
```

and it doesn't throw anything on this code

Furthermore, there is a place in my code where I do need create a global variable, so it would be nice to let jshint ignore that one. Is something like this possible ?

Comment: How are you running it? It is for me. IIRC the `undef` option will complain.

Comment: exactly what I need, if I set undef to 'true' I get the errors I need. For the intended global variable I now use `globals: { myGlob: true}` Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for undefined variables is `undef`, e.g.,

```
var options = {
    undef: true,     // Add this
    laxcomma: true,
    strict: true,
    validthis: true
};
```

Mine does this by default, I had to add the `laxcomma` bit, and that didn't disable the `undef` flag.